# Status of array with characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I was declaring a char array like this-

```
char str[16]= "The world is";
```

I know that its 13th character will be '\0'. But I am curious about rest of the character values till 16 in str. Are all of them assigned to '\0'. I searched it but could not find a good explanation. So I thought another fastest way is to ask here.:)

Comment: It means they must contain some garbage. Right?

Comment: If rest elements are zeros, and if I write something like str[12] = 'b'. and then print str, it will print "The world isb". But if all are zeros it should print something else. Because str will be printed by printf until it finds an '\0' character. Right?

Comment: I think they mean that rest will be '\0' instead of 0.

Comment: @doctorlove ah yes, the answer in that question is correct they are zeroed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest will contain zero. What you are actually doing is initializing your array as follows:

```
char str[16]= {'T','h','e',' ','w','o','r','l','d',' ','i','s','\0'};
```

If you initialize an array in C that you have given a length, with something that is shorter, C will fill the rest with 0.

Example: this will give an array filled with zero's

```
int str[16]= {0};
```

so what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
char str[16]= {'T','h','e',' ','w','o','r','l','d',' ','i','s','\0',0,0,0};
```

Note that `0 == '\0'` (both 0000...)

Comment: Oh!! 0 == '\0'. Now its clear. Thanks for help